SwiftUI Picker with Binding is not updating
I have implemented a Picker in a sheet like in the following code:
struct UserTabView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var userSkills: [LocalUserSkill]

    @State private var selectedSkill: LocalUserSkill?

    var body: some View {
        // ...
        UserSkillButton(selectedSkill: $selectedSkill, options: userSkills, title: "Skill")
    }
}

struct UserSkillButton: View {
    @Binding var selectedSkill: LocalUserSkill?
    var options: [LocalUserSkill]
    var title: String

    @State private var showingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Button(selectedSkill?.descript ?? "Select...") {
                showingSheet = true
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet, onDismiss: updateButtonLabel) {
                VStack {
                    Text(title)
                        .padding()
                    Picker("Wähle eine Option", selection: $selectedSkill) {
                        ForEach(options, id: \.userSkillId) { option in
                            Text(option.descript).tag(option)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                    .padding()

                    Button("Schließen") {
                        showingSheet = false
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .presentationDetents([.height(200)])
            }
        }
    }
}

i want to change the text from the button to the selectedSkill. But doesn't work.
LocalUserSkill looks like that...
@Model
public class LocalUserSkill {
    var adminNote: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var createdBy: String
    var descript: String
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var updatedBy: String
    var userSkillId: Int
    
    init(from skill: UserSkill) {
        self.adminNote = skill.adminNote
        self.createdAt = skill.createdAt?.foundationDate
        self.createdBy = skill.createdBy
        self.descript = skill.descript
        self.updatedAt = skill.updatedAt?.foundationDate
        self.updatedBy = skill.updatedBy
        self.userSkillId = skill.userSkillId
    }
}


@Bindable instead of @Binding

you could try using .sheet(item:...){....}
and using a tag type that matches the selectedSkill,
Text(option.descript).tag(Optional(option))

@workingdogsupportUkraine thanks, only changing it to Optional(option) worked for me!

Remove showingSheet and use sheet(item:) is best
